# How to get URL parameters in Angular JS, Node JS, Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

In angular I'm using the http service (get). I need to get the CURRENT url parameters to form the url of the http get. What is the best way to do this?

For example: the page I'm currently on is www.blah.com/blah1/blah2

I need to make a http get request in Angular with a url using blah1 and blah2 parameters. For example:

```
$http.get('www.lala.com/+blah1+blah2)
```

One solution I was thinking of: Use Node to pass in the url parameters to jade. Then in jade, initialize using ng-init with the passed in url parameters. Then I could access those ng-init variables (parameters) inside Angular?

Edit: I am an absolute beginner

Comment: Are you using an angular router? If so doing anything on server to parse path wouldn't make any sense

Comment: @charlietfl No I am not using an angular router

Comment: using an angular router might make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own wrapper for this requests getting url and you can parse them via this code ;

```
function parseURL(url) {
var parser = document.createElement('a'),
    searchObject = {},
    queries, split, i;
// Let the browser do the work
parser.href = url;
// Convert query string to object
queries = parser.search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');
for( i = 0; i < queries.length; i++ ) {
    split = queries[i].split('=');
    searchObject[split[0]] = split[1];
}
return {
    protocol: parser.protocol,
    host: parser.host,
    hostname: parser.hostname,
    port: parser.port,
    pathname: parser.pathname,
    search: parser.search,
    searchObject: searchObject,
    hash: parser.hash
};
}
```